# How can I get value from checkbox that is used in a Gridview's template field?

Tags: asp.net

I want to make an objective question/answer web project,in which I use a Gridview control to show questions and its options. I use CheckBox control as a template field for selecting  answer. How can I get the value of the selected CheckBox when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gridview get Checkbox.Checked value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628554/gridview-get-checkbox-checked-value)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936212/get-checkbox-value-in-gridview

Comment: I use a label and four checkbox as a template field in gridview.On label I display question and on first checkbox I display options A, on 2 nd checkbox display option B, on 3rd display C and on 4 th checkbox display option D.if I select A options and click on button then how to print the value of this checkbox on a texbox which is outside of the gridview?