# The name 'chk' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to c# and asp.net and I am trying to make a webform, that manages a collection of items.
I already managed to make form for add/search/edit, but I have some problems with delete.
My error is:
-Error  CS0103  The name 'chk' does not exist in the current context    (try.aspx.cs    Line: 74)
-Error  CS0119  'CheckBox' is a type, which is not valid in the given context(try.aspx.cs   Line: 74)

I have seen several question with the same error, but I still could not figure out where is my mistake.

**try.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="try.aspx.cs" Inherits="keszlet_management._try" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="KeszletGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="KeszletGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Item"
                HeaderText="Item" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Type"
                HeaderText="Type" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Owner"
                HeaderText="Owner" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ID" Visible="false" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="DelBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete Selected Rows" OnClick="DelBtn_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Msg"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

**try.aspx.cs:**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace keszlet_management
{
    public partial class _try : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet();
        }

        private void DataSet()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM items"))
                    {
                        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                sda.Fill(dt);
                                KeszletGrid.DataSource = dt;
                                KeszletGrid.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void DelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Count = 0;
            KeszletGrid.AllowPaging = false;
            KeszletGrid.DataBind();
            ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
            Count = arr.Count;
            for(int i=0;i<KeszletGrid.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                if(arr.Contains(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    DeleteRecord(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString());
                    arr.Remove(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
            }
            ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = arr;
            KeszletGrid.AllowPaging = true;
            DataSet();
        }
        private void GetData()
        {
            int i;
            ArrayList arr;
            if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
                arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
            else
                arr = new ArrayList();
            for (i = 0; i < KeszletGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
                if (CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)KeszletGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk"))
                {
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    if (!arr.Contains(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value))
                    {
                        arr.Add(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (arr.Contains(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    arr.Remove(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
        }
        ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = arr;
        }
        private void DeleteRecord(string ID)
        {
            string contrs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
            string query = "Delete From items Where id=@ID";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(contrs);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233630/variable-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Try using `(CheckBox)KeszletGrid.Rows[i].FindControl("chk")` instead.

Comment: This  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628554/gridview-get-checkbox-checked-value) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help you:

```
for (i = 0; i < KeszletGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    if (CheckBox chk = KeszletGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
```

or try this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in KeszletGrid.Rows) {
   if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("chk ") as CheckBox ;
   }
}
```

Comment: The main error still exist, no change were made in the CheckBox or chk (if(CheckBox chk = ...)

Comment: @kritikaTalwar, See Alan's comment below, you cannot declare a variable within an if condition, you can only assign an existing variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help @kritikaTalwar  it solved my problem!

Comment: pleasure helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this line 74?

```
if (CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)KeszletGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk"))
```

You can't declare chk and use it in the condition on the same line. Try this:

```
CheckBox chk = KeszletGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk") as CheckBox
if (chk != null && chk.Checked) {
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: The checkbox is in a `TemplateField` so it's not in a `Cell` in the row. Need to use the row's `FindControl`instead. But nice catch with the strange usage of if there.

Comment: @user1429080 Your original code is looking in a cell in the row for it though isn't it? I just copied your line and remove the type declaration.

Comment: I'm not the OP :-). Your suggestion, I believe, is on the right track, but not all the way to the goal. That's why I commented..

Comment: Ha ha, so you're not :)

Comment: I copy your code, and chk still "does not exist in the current context"
Another error after copy: "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement" (for : CheckBox chk = KeszletGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk") as CheckBox)

Comment: "You can't assign chk and use it in the condition on the same line", you can assign on the same line, you just can't create the variable itself inline. `CheckBox chk = null; if ((chk = (CheckBox)KeszletGrid).Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk"))`

Comment: @ColinM I should perhaps have said declare instead of assign.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `GetData` method to the following

You are not using code blocks in your `for` loop, and you are also missing some code blocks throughout the method.

Indenting on an `if` statement only works if there's one line of code, not multiple. There were also one or two close braces missing

```
private void GetData()
{
    int i;
    ArrayList arr;
    if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
        arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
    else
        arr = new ArrayList();
    for (i = 0; i < KeszletGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = null;
        if ((chk = (CheckBox)KeszletGrid).Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk"))
        {
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                if (!arr.Contains(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    arr.Add(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (arr.Contains(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    arr.Remove(KeszletGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```